# can't import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTzpC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PkrT.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seem like you don't sync project when add plugins.

Did you try resync project, or invalidate cache & restart IDE ???